# how to create a slide activity?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, swipe

I want to create an activity that I can slide left to right.

When I slide it, the distance between screen left and activity left is transparent,and I can move to ActivityB from ActivityA.

Example:

1. Open ActivityA
2. Slide to the left to start ActivityB

Here are two images for what I am looking for

[Picture1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8SGe.png)
[Picture2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frlkl.png)

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html#pagetransformer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

easiest option would be to just create a new android project/module in android studio and on the screen "Add an activity to mobile" choose tabbed activity (last option in studio 1.5.1). From there change the layout/logic as per your need.

Comment: thanks i have resolve it